# Locating Win10 driver

Tags: usb-debugging

Is it true that "the Google USB Driver is located in android_sdk\extras\google\usb_driver."`

Because I have none and I have installed Android Studio.

Comment: Verify that you've actually downloaded it. Read: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang it says "The best drivers are already installed" when I try to install the "USB driver".

Comment: Okay so what device are you trying to connect and what is specifically not working.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that "the Google USB Driver is located in
>   android_sdk\extras\google\usb_driver."

**Yes that's the default location where the downloaded google usb drivers are located.**

If you can't find them, then it may be that these were not downloaded in the first place. Be sure to download them through the sdk manager interface.

Alternatively you can always download the appropriate [OEM driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers) manually from the website and extract them to the default folder.

**Installing the USB driver**

- Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
- Press the <kbd>WIN Key</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd> buttons and select device manager
- In the Device Manager right pane, locate the device
  and right-click the name of the device you connected, and then select Update Driver Software.
- In the Hardware Update wizard, select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
- Click Browse and then locate the USB driver folder. You can also select the option; **Let me pick from from a list of device drivers on my computer** then browse for the driver. e.g, the Google USB Driver is located in `android_sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\`.
- Click Next to install the driver.